# Jenkins hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to generate a Jenkins hash from a string, in Perl.

```
    use Digest::JHash qw (jhash);

    $digest = jhash ("apa_mp_h_str_avunitm_01");
    print "$digest\n";
    exit 0;
```

It returns a 32 bit integer, 1303972418. It should become a signed int, -1546399138, to be precise. Whatever I try (like with Data::Integer), I can't for the life of me produce that number. Can anyone give me some pointers, please?

Comment: just FYI: you can use the Java/Groovy package for md5 directly in the pipeline without the need for a Perl script.

Comment: `1303972418` is `0x4db90a42`, which you can see is still a positive number when you cast it to a signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: "1303972418 is 0x4db90a42, which you can see is still a positive number"   Exactly. And I know, for a fact, that the prop in question produces -1546399138 as Jenkins hash (verified in CodeWalker).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the string `apa_mp_h_str_avunitm_01` to hash to `-1546399138`, you need [`Digest::OAT`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::OAT), not `Digest::JHash`, in order to use the correct hash function (The Wikipedia article on Jenkins' hash functions doesn't actually show the code for the original one that `Digest::JHash` implements; it has the later-developed one-at-a-time hash implemented in `Digest::OAT` and whatever you're using as a reference to get that value), and you need to coerce the hashed value to a signed 32 bit number (Because it normally returns an unsigned number, at least on 64bit perls. Not sure about 32bit builds):

```sh
# Normal output
$ perl -MDigest::OAT -E 'say Digest::OAT::oat("apa_mp_h_str_avunitm_01")'
2748568158
# Signed 32bit output
$ perl -MDigest::OAT -E 'say unpack("l", pack("l", Digest::OAT::oat("apa_mp_h_str_avunitm_01")))'
-1546399138
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, Shawn (and others). I'm not a math person, and CodeWalker (a tool for GTA V) has a 'create Jenkins hash' function I used to generate the -1546399138 output. Guess it wasn't Jenkins, after all.

Comment: @meimeiriver It was, just a different one - the guy's come up with 4 or 5 popular hash functions.

Answer (score 1):

For an input of `"apa_mp_h_str_avunitm_01"`, -1546399138 is the output of [this function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function#one_at_a_time). The [Digest::JHash::jhash implementation](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/Digest-JHash-0.10/JHash.xs#L41) is implementing something different, perhaps the `lookup2` or `lookup3` function described on the Wikipedia page in the first link. One indication of this is that the Perl `jhash` implement has the magic number [`0x9e3779b9`](https://metacpan.org/source/SHLOMIF/Digest-JHash-0.10/JHash.xs#L59), which does not appear in the simpler function.

Comment: The perl module looks like it implements Jenkins original hash function from the 90's Dr. Dobbs article. The one in the Wikipedia article is a later, different one. See http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html

Comment: I *think* this original one is what Wikipedia calls lookup2 based on the end of Bob's article.